# On torsion sheaf of a coherent sheaf of $\dim X$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, coherent-sheaves

$\underline {Background}$:Let,$E$ be a coherent sheaf on a Noetherian,integral scheme $X$ and $\dim E$=$\dim X$.

Then we have  the unique torsion filtration of that coherent sheaf as

$0\subset T_0(E)\subset....\subset T_{\dim X-1}(E) \subset T_{\dim X} (E)=E$

where,$T_i(E)$ is the maximal subsheaf of of $E$ of dimension $\leq i$

we also have torsion subsheaf of $E$ ,denoted by $T(E)$ which is defined as

for any affine $SpecA$ in $X$, define $ T(E)(SpecA)$:={$m \in E(SpecA)|\exists s\in A$  with $s$ nonzero such that $s.m=0$}

we also have $(T(E))_x=T(E_x)$

$\underline {Question}$:How do we show that  $T(E)=T_{\dim X-1}(E)$

I only know that  $T(E)$ is a subsheaf of $E$ ,and I am supposed to show the following

$T(E)$ is a maximal subsheaf of dimension $\leq \dim(X)-1$.

I have no clue how to show (i) it has dimension $\leq \dim(X)-1$ and

(ii) It is maximal among all such subsheaves.

Any help from anyone is welcome.

Comment: What do you mean by $\dim E$?

Comment: @Armandoj18eos $dim  E=dim(Supp( E))$